# use REST api to communicate to server using GSM client in arduino

Tags: rest, arduino, gsm

I am new to the arduino platform.
I want to use REST api for communication between my web server and GSM/GPRS.
i have  already created a REST api for communication between my android app and web server, but now i want to fire the same REST api(GET request) using GSM/GPRS client in arduino and want to read the response from the server.
FYI i am using arduino uno for atmega328-pu.
I tried searching in the web but ultimately ended up getting nothing useful.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From what you write, it is not entirely clear if you want to use the Arduino as a REST client or server. For setting up a server on it, your best bet will be to use the [Webduino](https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino) library that implements GET and POST methods.

Depending on the type of networking hardware (Wifi, Ethernet) you are using, there will be an implementation of the "Client" interface that you can use for sending HTTP requests. See this example for the Ethernet client: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

The code for the GSM client is in the GSM library, that you can find here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM

There's also a sample for using the GSM client: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebClient

Comment: thanks for taking interest, i wanted to make arduino as REST client . I am not using ethernet and wifi. i am using only GSM with gprs. so is there any header file available for implementing rest client using gprs ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which GSM/GPRS shield are you using? If it supports the [official GSM library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM) you can use that or if it is a Seeedstudio GPRS Shield use my [GSMGPRS_Shield](https://github.com/YellowOrb/GSMGPRS_Shield). Anyway then use my fork of [arduino-restclient](https://github.com/YellowOrb/arduino-restclient) or modify it if you use the default GSM library.

Let me know if that helps you. Otherwise I have some more examples etc I can post.